# Using PyMongo as Django backend

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo, tastypie

I'm writing an application with django and I want to use mongoDB as my database. I have searched around a lot and found mongoengine and Pymongo as possible choices. I have decided to got with PyMongo for the time being. But the thing is that I am unable to connect my app to mongoDB. I have tried following so far:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client['user_central']
```

But it doesn't work as it should. Something has to be put in the DATABASES django variable and that's where I'm caught up. How can I connect my django app to mongoDB and use mongo as my Django Backend??

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't put  DATABASES variable in settings file at all, Just start the MongoDB connection in any file in the project and start using it.

Answer (score 2):

Pymongo is not an ORM, is a driver, contains functions tools, to work with MongoDB.

Mongoengine it's a "*Document-Object Mapper (think ORM, but for document databases)*" based on pymongo. That is a better choice since you will use an 'ORM', similar with Django relational ORM.

In my opinion, [django-mongoengine](https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine) is a good option for using Django + MongoDB, is an OK integration, tough it has some problems, is not stable: "*THIS IS UNSTABLE PROJECT, IF YOU WANT TO USE IT - FIX WHAT YOU NEED*", but they are still working on it.

Configuring django-mongoengine is not really straight out of the box, is not described fully on their README.rst, but it can be done. They have an [example here](https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine/tree/master/example/tumblelog/tumblelog) of how to use it.

Note: Check django settings.py, there is described that Django is using a dummy (fake DB) and later they define 
a new setting MONGODB_DATABASES. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

**How can I connect my django app to mongoDB and use mongoDB as my Django Backend:**

First install djongo:

`pip install djongo`

Then run your migrations:

```
manage.py make migrations
manage.py migrate
```

and finally add to your settings file:

```
DATABASES = {
   ‘default’: {
      ‘ENGINE’: ‘djongo’,
      ‘NAME’: ‘your-db-name’,
   }
}
```

It is as simple as that!

As a web developer you can take up the challenge of connecting Django to MongoDB in two ways:

**Use a MongoDB compatible model framework**: Use a third party framework like [MongoEngine](https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine) or [Ming](https://github.com/amol-/ming) in your django projects. However will miss out on:

- 1500+ core contributors to the project,
- [Hourly fixes and ticket resolution](https://dashboard.djangoproject.com/),
- Ramp down on the expertise of existing Django models and ramp up on the new model framework.
- Perhaps the biggest drawback is that your project can’t use any of Django’s contrib models! Forget about using Admin, Sessions, Users, Auth, etc., contrib modules for your project!

**Django SQL to MongoDB transpiler — [Djongo](http://nesdis.github.io/djongo/)**: The strategy is to translate Django SQL query syntax generated by the Django ORM into pymongo commands. Djongo is a SQL to MongoDB query compiler. It translates every SQL query string into a mongoDB query document.

If you want to manipulate MongoDB using Django Admin, simply fire it up:

`manage.py runserver`

Goto: http://localhost:8000/admin/

Manipulate your embedded models as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

There is an article on [Using Django with MongoDB](https://medium.com/@SiddyZen/using-django-with-mongodb-by-adding-just-one-line-of-code-c386a298e179) by adding just one line of code, if you are looking for more information. Otherwise, you can jump directly into the [djongo documentation](http://nesdis.github.io/djongo/) and start using it.

Comment: I'm need to connect and read only a pre-existing mongodb database. Is there an example that show how can I do it with djongo, @nesdis?

Comment: There is a [tutorial](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/integrating-django-with-mongodb/) on how you can do it have you had a chance to take a look at it

Comment: Ok, thanks, @nesdis. I'm following the tutorial, in particular the Zero risk steps, but already have two problems: in my models file I added indexes but they are not added to the new empty clean db (the only indexes for any collections are id and primary_key); the second problem is: how do I do step 4 "Copy all data from existing db to new db" if I don't have primary_key for each doc?

Comment: You will need to write a small script that will read from one db and insert into the other. U can write the script in pymongo

Answer (score 0):

The Django ORM supports relational databases only, and MongoDB is not a relational database. Therefore, in theory it can't be supported by Django.

Despite that, there exist custom backends such as [mongodb-engine](https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine), which pretend to Django that MongoDB is relational. This, in my opinion, is a very ugly hack that will explode at the worst possible moment. If you want to use a non-relational database, don't use the Django ORM.

If you are a beginner, just use SQLite.

Comment: I get it but for some reason I do have to use pymongo. How can I use it as django backend (even if it means I dont use django ORM)? I mean how can I connect my django app to mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

As a less convenient (not auto-plugged to django's features) but valid way, you could deploy MongoDB as a standalone locally on your computer or on a remote server.

Then, initiate the PyMongo object with the URL of your mongoDB service to interface with.

This way you use DB calls outside of Django's features, but straight forward from the user code.

- If using Linux, I prefer using the mongoDB docker container.

  `$ docker run --name mongodb -p 27017:27017 --net mynet mongo`

and then using:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'
client = pymongo.MongoClient(url)
db = client['db_name']
```

- This is how I'd use MongoDB without Frameworks (or other, for example [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/))

[MongoDB Docker Official](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo)