# Django, GraphQL, Mongo - graphene-mongo the only possibility?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, graphene-python, graphene-django

I was planning on building a new software using 3 popular technologies: Python, MongoDB and a GraphQL API (Frontend with Angular, but that is not the focus of this post).

Although a combination of these three technologies should not be that rare it seems as though the support is extremely limited. The only framework combining these technologies that I have found graphene-python. The support for flask is super limited, the support for django is okay.

BUT: I am not sure as to what is happening right now. The last release of graphene-python was more than one year ago. Issues are not answered for multiple weeks. Using it I have experienced multiple issues that seem to have been fixed partially in the repository but not in the official package. Am I missing something? This is not meant to be critique, I am just not sure as to whether I should base our new architecture on that framework.

Is there a different framework for that techstack? I know that developing a graphql API could also be done manually but it just doesn't sit right with me.

Comment: Graphene relies on the ORM for database manipulations, so databases can easily be swapped out with no problem. Therefore, you just need to connect Mongo to Django normally. https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/mongodb-and-django

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45957026/using-pymongo-as-django-backend

Thank you for your answer. Django can't deal with mongodb out of the box, therefore it is not just replacing the driver. Especially in combination with graphql the support will shrink down extremely.